How to access the Ubuntu 22.04 KVM Host OpenVPN connection from a Windows 10 KVM VM
My local network consists of a class C IPv4 LAN. The DHCP address pool ranges from 192.168.30.20 to 192.168.30.119.
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 KVM Host machine that gets it's IP assigned by DHCP.
There is also a bridge br0 set up in netplan/networkd (netplan.io 1.0) that is used by the KVM client VMs.
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - enp3s0

This KVM Host connects to an OpenVPN server on the internet and the LAN of the remote network behind the OpenVPN server is also a class C IPv4 LAN: 192.168.50.x. These machines can all be reached from the KVM host.
Now, with the OpenVPN connection active on the KVM host, ip a results in:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:59:56:65:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether be:d2:3e:61:fb:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.30.42/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.30.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 80892sec preferred_lft 80892sec
    inet6 2a02:a46b:7ca0:1:bcd2:3eff:fe61:fbf9/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 172877sec preferred_lft 86477sec
    inet6 fe80::bcd2:3eff:fe61:fbf9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.2/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::44b6:a31c:c9d7:59a1/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

The routes available on the KVM host are:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.30.254  0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 br0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
8.1.2.3         192.168.30.254  255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 br0
192.168.30.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br0
192.168.30.254  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 br0
192.168.50.0    10.8.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0

with 8.1.2.3 representing the remote OpenVPN server IP
All is good so far, the Windows 10 VM gets an IP assigned in the local network range 192.168.30.x. From the VM I can access all local LAN IP's 192.168.30.x and anything on the internet. However I am not able to access the OpenVPN network from the Windows 10 client VM that uses the br0 bridge interface.
Any help on how to achieve this from here on would be greatly appreciated.
